# anchor navigation and history changes

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, browser-history

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="./page1.html">page 1</a>
```

When clicking on the link, a new history entry added as expected.
Now I change this to:

```
<a href="./page1.html" onclick="func(event)">page 1</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(event) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, '', "./page1.html");
}
</script>
```

Now, when I click on this link, the history doesn't change.
I don't manage to understand why. I didn't prevented the anchor's action (by `event.preventDefault()` or returning false) so I expected from the anchor to add new history entry as it should...
What happend first? the link navigation or the history change?
I would love to get an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, testing in both Firefox and Chrome, navigating a link to the current page does not modify the browser history. Both browsers seem to treat it as a "refresh" rather than navigation.

This means that your second example is effectively replacing the current history state twice (once with the javascript, then again with the default navigation).

Here's the code I was using for testing. Comment/uncomment the `replaceState` to see the difference (there is none). Note: I found it helpful to turn on Persist in Firebug to keep my console log from getting cleared during the navigation.

```
<a href="./page1.html" onclick="func(event)">page 1</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(event) {
    console.log("before: " + window.history.length);
    //window.history.replaceState(null, '', "./page1.html");
    console.log("after: " + window.history.length);
}
onload = function() { console.log("load: " + window.history.length);}
</script>
```

I haven't been able to find any references for why the browsers work this way. It's pretty easy to verify using your first example, though. Click the link 20 times; your back button will stay disabled.

## Update Using Two Pages

page0.html

```
<a href="./page1.html" onclick="func(event)">page 1</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(event) {
    console.log("before: " + window.history.length);
    window.history.replaceState(null, '', "./page1.html");
    console.log("after: " + window.history.length);
}
onload = function() { console.log("load: " + window.history.length);}
</script>
```

page1.html

```
Page 1
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function() { console.log("load: " + window.history.length);}
</script>
```

Here's what I get in the console when clicking the link

```
load: 1           page0.html (line 8)
before: 1         page0.html (line 4)
after: 1          page0.html (line 6)
load: 1           page1.html (line 3)
load: 1           page1.html (line 3)
```

What I think is happening:

1. User clicks link
2. `func` is called
3. Current history state is replaced with `page1.html`
4. Browser "navigates" to `page1.html`, the page it is already on (step 3), but treats it as a refresh since it's the same page.

Comment: James, as long as the anchor has href of the same current page, you are right. But I am talking about a situation where the anchor refers to other page. Can you made those tests again with an anchor to other url? What did you get? What do you think the reason to that behavior?

Comment: I see what you mean. I updated the answer using two pages. Based on the testing I think it's basically the same thing happening, regardless if it's one page or two.

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what I was looking for: how to prevent adding to history when clicking an anchor link (in my case to a hash id). I hope this is intended behaviour!